# CSS is shown for the image in the developer tools. What does this mean?

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

[image]

What does it mean to be thinly marked?
The CSS seems to be applied, but I am curious to know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "photo-thin"?

Comment: @Justin Taddei
Translation was not working well.. We have rewritten it. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Greyed out stuff means it's not active right now. Don't confuse this with overwritten by a higher specifity which is shown as strike through.

Comment: I assume you mean the properties that are semi-transparent. Those are properties that were not applied to the current element, but only to the parent they are defined on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Comment: @cloned
Thank you. What does it mean when inactive? That CSS seemed to play a role. If I unchecked the checkbox, the display changed and I couldn't figure it out, hence my question.

Comment: @TiiJ7
Well, it certainly seems that way. I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @TiiJ7 explained it better. I meant "Not active" for the current element. The reason is, as Tiij said, that this is because they are only on the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood by his answer. Thank you very much.

I assume you mean the properties that are semi-transparent. Those are properties that were not applied to the current element, but only to the parent they are defined on. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance –
TiiJ7
Sep 16 at 7:01